# Создание системы отношений на django

Tags: python, django

Каким образом можно организовать систему отношений в django? Мне нужна возможность добавить/удалить из друзей, принять/отклонить заявку в друзья и подобное, но не могу представить с помощью каких средств это осуществить.Желательно не готовое приложение, а подтолкнуть меня к решению, т.к. только учусь.

Comment: Ну ты злодей! http://hashcode.ru/questions/132056/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-django

Comment: Да, злодей. Но меня все таки интересует какими полями можно это добиться, в виде отдельного класса или внутри самого пользователя. Одним словом мне нужна архитектура и пинок в правильном направлении

Comment: автор видимо случайно ткнул в прошлом вопросе на правильный ответ, при этом ответа толком не получив.

Comment: Да, что то типа того. Там мне больше было интересно есть ли готовые решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала определись сколько тебе нужно функционала в системе отношений, если полный функционал как в ВК(друзья, заявки, подписки), то понадобится три модели  такого типа:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="person_subscribers")

class Friendship(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="friends")
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

class FriendshipRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                                related_name="friendship_requests_to")
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                                  related_name="friendship_requests_from")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=REQUEST_STATUS,
                              default=CREATED)
```

К ним еще менеджеры с кучей методов, если без подписчиков, то уже проще.

Comment: Так уже интереснее. Подписки точно не будет. Спасибо за совет